# Lookup without record type

Tags: custom-object, lookup

I've created a custom object(File__c) which can be related to any standard or custom object. Currently I'm doing it with 2 fields, one to store the destination object id(String), and one for destination object type(String). If destination object type wasn't a variable, this would ideally be a lookup relationship.

Is there a way to create lookup using just the destination object id & without knowing the destination object type? Any other better way to do this?

Comment: I assume the ID is stored as a String, since you cannot create a polymorphic Lookup in custom objects (quite annoying). If so, the records will not be portable from one org to another. Anyway, an ID has a prefix that can be used to obtain the object type from that ID. Take a look at [Id](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_id.htm) documentation for details. I have assumed you mean the object type rather than "record type", which would be `RecordTypeId` on the referenced SObject record.

Comment: You should [edit] the question to include object model details.

Comment: @PhilW thanks. Updated the question a little. I can save ID as string, but there is no way to make it a lookup relationship right?

Comment: Correct. So why do you need the object type separately? What do you use it for?

Comment: In apex, I need to get the associated record details and object type is used for those queries. With the ID prefix, I can avoid that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every object type results in a unique (on the org) three character prefix applied to the IDs for the records of that object type.

Since you are storing the ID as a string, if you need to select `File__c` records that "relate" to records of a given object you can use [DescribeObjectResult.getKeyPrefix](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_Schema_DescribeSObjectResult_getKeyPrefix) to translate an object type to an ID prefix, thus:

```
String objectType = ...;
SObject obj = (SObject) Type.forName(objectType).newInstance();
DescribeSObjectResult describe = obj.getSObjectType().getDescribe();
String idPrefixLike = '%' + describe.getKeyPrefix();
```

You can then use this in your query, like:

```
List<File__c> files = [SELECT Id, ... FROM File__c WHERE RecordId__c LIKE :idPrefixLike ...];
```

(I have assumed the field holding the ID as a string is called `RecordId__c`.)

On the other hand, if you are simply getting `File__c` instances and want the `RecordId__c` translated to an object type, simply:

```
List<File__c> files = ...;

for (File__c file : files) {
    SObjectType objectType = Id.valueOf(file.RecordId__c).getSObjectType();

    ...
}
```

From `SObjectType` you can get the `DescribeObjectResult` as you need.